# product export duplicate row in Magento 2.1.2

Tags: export, magento-2.1.2

I try to export products from admin as

Open admin panel
Edit any product
Add description that has quotes "
Save Product
Go to System - Export - Products
Export products
[image]

it should be single row for one record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got solution from this blog. http://magento2error.blogspot.in/2017/08/product-export-duplicate-rows-for.html

it's known magento bug noticed https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7350

Comment: I have same issue and I try this but it not work. My Magento version is 2.2.5.

Comment: I also had same issue related to duplicate rows, have you found solution @Divyarajsinh ??